# Sorting seach results in Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

The issue is how can user sort questions for a particular search query?

For example, I would want to search questions for [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) and want to see newest questions first.

Right now If we write any query in *Search Questions...* input box then users are not able to select sorting options as search questions input box takes whole width of the screen and sorting options box gets hidden.

I have also tried to select sorting options first and then search for [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) but still its showing questions without considering sorting option I have selected.

[image]

Comment: No one is facing this issue in android app? I want to check latest threads for Android-app tag, how can I?

Comment: I get your point/issue. I posted a similar question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193459/order-by-filter-does-not-apply-on-the-search-results

Comment: @geff_chang yes it seems more of possible duplicate.

Comment: You're not the only one. I just got the beta invite yesterday and wanted to look at the newest questions in a tag I tend to monitor... and couldn't.

Comment: I should also add that "Unanswered (my tags)" returned no results even though I know that at the time there were a few that should have been returned.

Comment: To be clear, this has nothing to do with tags, it applies to _any_ search results.

Comment: The issue is not limited to Tag Searches. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed] in  v0.1.47

Answer (score 4):

Sorting search results is now possible as of version v0.1.47.

Comment: Yes I can see but I think there should be a guidelines or FAQ for searching questions like if you would want to search for android tag then you need to input [android], likewise for other tags and many other searching terms.