# Order by filter does not apply on the search results

Tags: bug, android-app

When I select `Votes` in the Order by filter, type in a search word and trigger the search, the search results seems to follow the `Relevance` filter instead of the `Votes` filter. I assume this is also the same for the other Order by filter.

**EDIT #1:** I think my question may be a duplicate or is related to this question: [Sorting seach results in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192432/sorting-questions-for-the-particular-tag-in-android-app)